# in ReactiveUI binding, How to disable 2 buttons by 2 ReactiveCommand

Tags: wpf, reactiveui

I'm using ReactiveCommand and bind it to a button and let the button be disabled automatically when the command is executing, it works great.

Now I have 2 ReactiveCommand and 2 buttons, I want the 2 buttons to be disabled when any of the command is executing. What I tried is:

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass()
        {
            ReadClFilesCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(ReadClFiles, c.IsExecuting.Select(exe => !exe));            

            WriteClFilesCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(WriteClFiles, ReadClFilesCommand.IsExecuting.Select(exe => !exe));
        }
    }
```

It looks very elegent and I like its cleanness. But when I try to run the code, I got an `NullReferenceException` for `WriteClFilesCommand` because it's not created yet.

I guess I need to create the command first and then set its CanExecute later, but `CanExecute` is readonly.

Maybe I can create a separate IObserable and let in `ReadClFilesCommand.CanExecute` and `WriteClFilesCommand.CanExecute`, is it possible?

Any other ways to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still using RxUI 6 so my syntax is a little different but I think either of these ways will work. The WhenAny* helpers are your best friend whenever something isn't available yet or if you don't know when it will be available. As long as you have it setup so setting those commands will throw an INotifyPropertyChanged event.

```
        IObservable<bool> canExecute =
            Observable.CombineLatest(
                this.WhenAnyObservable(x=> x.WriteClFilesCommand.IsExecuting),
                this.WhenAnyObservable(x => x.ReadClFilesCommand.IsExecuting))
                .Select(x => !x.Any(exec => exec));


        ReadClFilesCommand = 
            ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncObservable(
                canExecute,
                ReadClFiles);

        WriteClFilesCommand = 
            ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncObservable(
                canExecute,
                WriteClFiles);
```

Or you can use a subject to "play" all your events through

```
        BehaviorSubject<bool> canExecute = new BehaviorSubject<bool>(true);


        ReadClFilesCommand =
            ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncObservable(
                canExecute,
                ReadClFiles);

        WriteClFilesCommand =
            ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncObservable(
                canExecute,
                WriteClFiles);

        Observable.CombineLatest(
                WriteClFilesCommand.IsExecuting,
                ReadClFilesCommand.IsExecuting)
                .Select(x => !x.Any(exec => exec))
                .Subscribe(canExecute);
```

Comment: I use your second solution and it works, even to auto disable 3 buttons, :-)